# How to add values in a variable in Unix shell scripting?

Tags: unix

I have two variables called count1 and count7

```
count7=0
count7=$(($count7 + $count1))
```

This shows an error "expression is not complete; more token required".

How should I add the two variables?

Comment: What is `count1` set to?  If it is not set, it looks like the empty string - and that would lead to an invalid expression.  Which shell are you using?

Comment: kshell and count1 is set to some value. Is there any other way that we can add the count continously coming out from a loop like arrays?

Comment: You need to explain what your real problem is, then.  One possible issue can be if you have a pipeline and are adding the result in a loop in the pipeline, then it is processed in a sub-shell, and you can't get at the updated result in the parent shell.  But you need to show more code before we can make that diagnosis.  What you showed strongly suggests that `$count1` is not set to what you think it is set to.

Answer (score 26):

What is `count1` set to? If it is not set, it looks like the empty string - and that would lead to an invalid expression. Which shell are you using?

In Bash 3.x on MacOS X 10.7.1:

```
$ count7=0
$ count7=$(($count7 + $count1))
-sh: 0 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
$ count1=2
$ count7=$(($count7 + $count1))
$ echo $count7
2
$
```

You could also use `${count1:-0}` to add 0 if `$count1` is unset.

Answer (score 7):

In `ksh` ,`bash` ,`sh`:

```
$ count7=0                     
$ count1=5
$ 
$ (( count7 += count1 ))
$ echo $count7
$ 5
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var=$((count7 + count1))
```

Arithmetic in bash uses `$((...))` syntax.

You do not need to `$` symbol within the `$(( ))`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as well. Can be faster for quick calculations:

```
echo $[2+2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example to add two variables:

```
var1=4
var2=3
let var3=$var1+$var2
echo $var3
```

Answer (score 1):

the above script may not run in ksh. you have to use the 'let' opparand to assing the value and then echo it.

```
val1=4

val2=3

let val3=$val1+$val2

echo $val3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo "$x"
    x=10
    echo "$y"`enter code here`
    y=10
    echo $[$x+$y]
```

Answer: 20

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a unix system under my hands, but try this:

`count7=$((${count7} + ${count1}))`

Or maybe you have a shell that doesn't support this expression.
I think `bash` does support it, but `sh` doesn't.

EDIT: There is another syntax, try:

```
count7=`expr $count7 + $count1`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read num1
read num2
sum=`expr $num1 + $num2`
echo $sum
```