# Display variable, plus one

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a var called YEAR which is 16

I want to create a new variable called FINYEAR which is 16/17

I.e. it is YEAR, and then '/', and then 'YEAR+1'

This question 
[How to add values in a variable in Unix shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245862/how-to-add-values-in-a-variable-in-unix-shell-scripting)

does not seem to cover it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(( ))` to do an arithmetic expansion:

```
$ year=16
$ finyear="$year/$(( year + 1 ))"
$ echo "$finyear"
16/17
```

Note that `$` are not needed in front of variable names inside `$(( ))` because names are unambiguous. Also note that I am intentionally using lowercase variable names - [don't use uppercase names in your scripts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/style#variable_names)!

Answer (score 0):

Use arithmetic expansion:

```
FINYEAR="$YEAR/$((YEAR+1))"
```